# The delta V required for given cordinates intersection on given time

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, delta-v

The spacecraft is on a LEO orbit with known keplerian elements. The equation of motion for spacecraft is also known.

I have to intersect (just intersect!) the given coordinates $X$, $Y$, $Z$ on near, LEO orbit. Departure and Arrival times are given. $\Delta V$ is applied in an instant.
X,Y,Z is on different plane.

How to calculate the required $\Delta V$?

I made research about the 'Hohmann transfer orbit' and 'vis-viva equation'. However, I can't understand how to intersect a point on another orbit exactly on time $T$?

Comment: I'd recommend that you first take a look around at the other questions and answers here, you can click the tags that you've chosen (`orbital-maneuver`, `orbital-mechanics`, `delta-v`) and see the level of discussion and math involved in working on even one small part of this. This is like going to stackoverflow and saying "I have a core-i7 processor, 12 Volts AC, and a six-pack of Mountain Dew. I need an operating system, ideas?" :)

Comment: İ thougt my question is clear enough :) İ'm looking on other questions now

Comment: Oh it is very clear, but it is just a *huge question*! Try to narrow down to some small part of the problem, and ask something more specific.

Comment: Edited the question. The question should have analytic solution, so I'm looking for ideas

Comment: Well, I think others will ask you the standard questions, like "what have you tried so far?" or if they are nice, they will point you to other answers here and ask you why those answers are not sufficient. Good luck!

Comment: Pointing to other answers, or giving references, where I could read exactly about this would be Perfect!

Comment: 1) This may help, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit. 2) A key assumption of a Hohmann transfer is that the manoeuvres are assumed to be impulsive, i.e. the whole delta V is applied in an instant.  3) The time for the transfer is the time spent in the orbital drift, in the simple case of a Hohmann transfer this is a half of the orbital period of the transfer orbit.

Comment: Yes! But in my case it's not Hohmann orbit, as I have given arrival/departure time and final coordinates. The only unknown is Velocity

Comment: 4) You don't mention whether the x,y,z point is in the same plane as the original orbit. This would simplify things.  5) You haven't mentioned any constraint as to whether you need to be in any particular orbit when intersecting x,y,z. This provides sufficient freedom that the Hohmann transfer may not be the best approach (why did you put Hohmann in the question?). 6) After all these points, you must search for an orbital arc that fits your start and finish points and from this you can calculate the delta V from Vis-viva.

Comment: 4) Different planes. Edited. 5) I need just to intersect the coordinates. 6) I don't know what to search for. Could you give some hints?

Comment: @Puffin Could you please answer in more detail about 6) in Answer form?

Comment: @Puffin in vis-viva there is nothing about TIME. I have given arrival and departure time.

Comment: The vis-viva just gives you the velocity of an orbiting object at some point on an ellipse defined by the radius at that point.  This is looking like a homework question so it will help you a lot to draw a diagram of your starting orbit and the point you are interested in. Try this in an in-plane case first as it will help. On top of this you then need to draw another ellipse that goes from somewhere, lets call it point A, on the first orbit to your target.  The problem is to find an ellipse that reaches from A to the target whilst matching your times.

Comment: Clearly this is going to involve some iteration. You will probably need something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly to calculate the times.

Comment: I edited the question, trying to  simplify the question. So, how to calculate semimajor axis for 2 points and time?

Comment: That last edit could really do with a diagram, its not at all clear.

Comment: What kind of diagram? Do you mean numerical iterative solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding the orbit that connects two points with a given transit time is known as [Lambert's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem), and has a small set of solutions. Once you have that orbit, you just need to subtract the velocities of the old and new orbit at the starting point of the new orbit.

Comment: Thanks! I'll research now. Is this solution is better than building the Hohmann transfer orbit, which would comply with my transfer time?

Comment: It is the only solution. The constraints you stated are the Lambert problem constraints, and they result in unique solutions to meet those constraints. This has nothing to do with Hohmann transfers.

Comment: Another question: How the problem would change, if the TRANSFER TIME is unknown, but the DELTA-V is minimal?

Comment: Then you would generate the Lambert solutions for a range of transfer times, and look for a minimum in the $\Delta V$ magnitude. That would be a one-dimensional version of a [porkchop plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porkchop_plot), where in two dimensions the Lambert solutions between two moving planets is plotted as a function of departure and arrival times.

Comment: Thanks! Last question, I've already marked your answer as correct: What if arrival time and coordinates are given, but departure time and coordinates are unknown? I could build a Hohmann orbit, calculate the transfer time, and then calculate the departure time and coordinates. Would it be more optimal?

Comment: Then set the departure time to the arrival time and the two sets of coordinates to be the same. Then zero $\Delta V$. Done.

Comment: Time and coordinates the same? I didn't understand your approach. Also, would this method be more optimal, than using Lambert problem with given time and coordinates?

Comment: The point is that your last problem is not well posed. It can be solved with no change in orbit at all.

Comment: I solved the BVP using shooting method, however the result is not optimal. Sometimes the flight is in reverse direction!